# PHP loop not displaying properly

Tags: php, loops

I need some help with a looping problem. For my example code below, I have two Mysql tables:

```
tblDepRatesCats:

ID 
header 
left_text 
center_text 
right_text 
header_order

------

tblRates_balance:

id 
depratecat 
MinBalance 
InterestRate 
APY 
suborder
```

The `tblDepRatesCats.ID =  tblRatesBalance.depratecat`. For each row in `tblDepRatesCats`, there may be 0 or 1 or more rows in `tblRates_balance`.

I'm trying to display the results of querying these tables so that it shows each `tblDepRatesCats` data with the corresponding `tblRates_balance` data, but instead it is showing  `tblDepRatesCats` so that if `tblDepRatesCats` row has 3 `tblDepRatesCats` rows associted with it, the  `tblDepRatesCats` row is repeated 3 times with one row of `tblDepRatesCats`'

As you can see below "Super Now Checking Account" is displayed 3 times, but what I want is for it to display just once with the 3 results for minimum balance and apy listed under the one header.

> NOW Checking Accounts  Minimum Daily Balance to Earn APY  Annual
>   Percentage Yield $1000                                    10
>
> Super NOW Checking Account  Minimum Daily Balance to Earn APY  Annual
>   Percentage Yield % $2222                                2
>
> Super NOW Checking Account  Minimum Daily Balance to Earn APY  Annual
>   Percentage Yield % $2100                                25
>
> Super NOW Checking Account  Minimum Daily Balance to Earn APY  Annual
>   Percentage Yield % $2000                                20
>
> Money Market Accounts  Minimum Daily Balance to Earn APY  Annual
>   Percentage Yield % $3000                               30

Below is my test code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT tblDepRatesCats.*, tblRates_balance.* FROM tblDepRatesCats JOIN tblRates_balance ON tblDepRatesCats.ID = tblRates_balance.depratecat ORDER BY tblDepRatesCats.header_order, tblRates_balance.suborder;');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
 echo ("<table width=\"98%\" border=\"0\" bgcolor:\"#ffffff\"><tr><td>");
 echo ("" . $row["header"] . " <br>");
 echo ("" . $row["left_text"] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
 echo ("" . $row["right_text"] . "");
 echo ("</tr></td>");
 // &nbsp temporarily added
 echo ("<tr><td>");
 echo ("" . $row["MinBalance"] . "");
 echo ("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
 echo ("" . $row["InterestRate"] . " <br><br>");
 echo ("</tr></td>");
}
```

Comment: You should stop using **Mysql_***, it's been depreciated. Check out MySqli or PDO.

Comment: In query result , records repeated. You have to check your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you right, then all you need to do is shift around your code:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT tblDepRatesCats.*, tblRates_balance.* FROM tblDepRatesCats JOIN tblRates_balance ON tblDepRatesCats.ID = tblRates_balance.depratecat ORDER BY tblDepRatesCats.header_order, tblRates_balance.suborder;');
$new_result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
  $new_result[$row["header"]][] = $row;
}

foreach($new_result as $new_row){
  echo ("<table width=\"98%\" border=\"0\" bgcolor:\"#ffffff\"><tr><td>");
  echo ("" . $new_row[0]["header"] . " <br>");
  echo ("" . $new_row[0]["left_text"] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  echo ("" . $new_row[0]["right_text"] . "");
  echo ("</tr></td>");

  foreach($new_row as $row){
   // &nbsp temporarily added
   echo ("<tr><td>");
   echo ("" . $row["MinBalance"] . "");
   echo("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
   echo ("" . $row["InterestRate"] . " <br><br>");
   echo ("</tr></td>");
  }

  //also, dont forget to close the table:
  echo "</table>";
}
```

The way your code was was starting a new table everytime you went through your loop

edit to avoid warning. Though it might make more sense to find a way to not need to have to call `$result[0]["xxxxx"]` at all. Maybe a static variable would be easier, though a second query to get just those values might be what you are looking for. It just depends

Comment: I tried to move the while loop, but now I get an error repeated 3 times:Notice: Undefined variable: row in  on line 10..11..12. Do I need another while loop somewhere?

Comment: I need the results to display like this: 
<br>
NOW Checking Accounts 
Minimum Daily Balance to Earn APY Annual Percentage Yield 
$1000                                        10

Super NOW Checking Account
Minimum Daily Balance to Earn APY Annual Percentage Yield % 
$2222                                         2
$2100                                       25
$2000                                         20

Money Market Accounts 
Minimum Daily Balance to Earn APY Annual Percentage Yield % 
$3000

Comment: and those edits, sorry for the bugs... hopefully I got them all this time

Comment: Sorry, guess I'm not explaining myself very well. I'm been trying to edit my answers but the site keeps cutting me off.

Comment: For my test, the results should display NOW Checking Accounts with one row under it. The Super Now should show 3 rows. The Money Market should show one row.

Comment: Gotcha, how about that?

Comment: Getting an error on this line $new_result[$row["header"][] = $row; ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']'

Comment: Getting a different error now:
Notice: Undefined offset: 0, in these rows:echo ("" . $new_result[0]["header"] . " <br>");
  echo ("" . $new_result[0]["left_text"] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
  echo ("" . $new_result[0]["right_text"] . "");

Comment: ... I deserve lashes or something for the number of errors I have had... anything else? lol

Comment: Excellent! Working great. Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the output you don't want to be repeated each time to outside of the while loop...

```
echo ("<table width=\"98%\" border=\"0\" bgcolor:\"#ffffff\"><tr><td>");
echo ("" . $row["header"] . " <br>");
echo ("" . $row["left_text"] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
echo ("" . $row["right_text"] . "");
echo ("</tr></td>");
echo ("<tr><td>");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    //&nbsp temporarily added
    echo ("" . $row["MinBalance"] . "");
    echo ("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    echo ("" . $row["InterestRate"] . " <br><br>");
}
echo ("</tr></td>");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use left join if there can be 0 links between tables. Using join only will result rows that have no data in balance table to be dropped out from results.